# Unable to connect to SQL server from RHEL server 7.4 using Kerberos

Tags: sql-server, linux, redhat, kerberos, sqlcmd

So I'm trying to connect to one of our SQL server from a RHEL Server 7.4 machine, I already installed Kerberos, [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) and [Microsoft ODBC for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).

The SQL server I'm trying to connect to is inside Active Directory (AD) domain, I was able to authenticate through that using `kinit` but still getting `SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database.` error.

This is my snippet from terminal:

```
[RH@localhost /]$ sudo kinit rh@ADS.LOCAL.COM
[sudo] password for RH: 
Password for rh@ADS.LOCAL.COM: 
[RH@localhost /]$ sqlcmd -E -S MyServer
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SSPI Provider: Server not found in Kerberos database.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

This is my `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = yes
 default_realm = ADS.LOCAL.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
 dns_lookup_kdc = true

[domain_realm]
 .ads.local.com = ADS.LOCAL.COM
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did the answer below work? I am having the same problems? It didn't work for me.. but if it did for you it might mean that my problem is with my krb5.conf file.. but I dont know

Answer (score 0):

Usage of Fully Qualified Host Name (FQHN) of the server should solve the problem. For example:

```
sqlcmd -E -S MyServer.ADS.LOCAL.COM
```

And if the issue presists, run `kinit` without `sudo` see if it helps.